# disallow to view folder's file when it doesn't have a Default.aspx in it

Tags: c#, file, hide

Let 'Project/' be the main folder of the project.
If for example I had the folder 'Project/a', but it doesn't contain a Default.aspx file, how can I hide the files in it?

When I have for example, a folder as the above, the ASP.NET generates a list with all the files in it.

C# ASP.NET Visual Web Developer 2008 Express

Comment: Hide it how? From the solution? In IIS?

Comment: When you publish you webapp to IIS, directory browsing will be turned off by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this option in the `web.config` file for the folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Through the IIS 7 Manager, this is under the "Directory Browsing" option.